# Why are my contacts not working?

Tags: ipod

So on my iPod generation 4, I go into my cloud contacts and type my friends name like" amy(: Bestfriend" and then I'll save that and go to my messages and her name will pop up as "Amy then her last name".  I don't get why the name I saved it as isn't showing up.. It did before! Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently hookup your Facebook account to your iPod? Typically when you do that it imports the contacts Facebook name for use on your phone/iPod. If you go to Settings->Facebook you can turn off contacts.

Also you may want to try and delete that conversation, then start it over with the new contact (go right from contacts to send message).

Hope that helps!